# How to generate a bar chart using TeeChart in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, teechart

I am generating TeeCharts in Classic ASP application. It is a relatively old application and I need to generate a new chart in it. I have all the data in place and using the that data I am able to generate a perfect Line Chart. However, using the same data I would like to generate a bar chart. I have tried all available options but am not able to generate a bar chart. I am not getting any error, the chart simply fails to show up.
Can anyone please post a sample code to generate a simple bar chart.

Nupur Modi

Comment: I think your question will benefit more if you let people see your code - perhaps someone will spot the reason.

Answer (score 0):

TeeChart comes with demos (ASP.NET demo included), tutorials and documentation. Have you looked at them?
To create a Bar series you just have to create an instance of the Bar class and give it the Chart (in the following case tChart1 is a TChart):

```
Bar bar1 = new Bar(tChart1.Chart);
```

After it you, just have to populate the series. You have several overrides of the `Add()` function for it. But fora a simple test, you may want to try with sample values:

```
bar1.fillSampleValues();
```

And that's it. If the chart is correctly created - and it should because you say the Line series is correctly shown - it should also work for the Bar series.

Comment: Please make a note that I am working in a Classic ASP application with TeeChart version 5. When I write this line Bar bar1 = new Bar(tChart1.Chart); it give me error. This works fine in ASP.Net, but not in Classic ASP.